# Bash's equivalent of Tcsh's ESC+p

Tags: bash, inputrc

I'm moving from Tcsh to Bash, and I would like to take the <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> feature with me.

If I type , say `git cl`, and then press <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, it should complete automatically to the last command that starts with `git cl` (e.g. `git clone something`), **and place the cursor at the end**.

I added the following 2 lines to `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\ep": history-search-backward
"\en": history-search-forward
```

which gives me exactly what I need except that the cursor is not moved to the end.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
"\ep": "\M-\C-p\C-e"
"\M-\C-p": history-search-backward
```

The first line defines a "macro" that inserts two keystrokes, \M-\C-p and \C-e.  The first keystroke you define as history-search-backward, and the 2nd is already defined as end-of-line.

Comment: Adding this to my inputrc right now, something I was curious about myself!

Comment: It works, but I didn't think about what it would do to searching through multiple entries. I usually will type in ssh and go through the history search. Moving the cursor to the end of the line kind of ruins that.

Comment: Exactly - I don't care for this command combination myself, because as you say it breaks searching through multiple matching entries.  But it's what Misha asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `control-r` first (or once the common part of the command typed, like after `git`, then typing the rest and hitting `End` will do it in the same number of key-presses as `Esc-P` :)